Is there a good reason to have separate [food-science] and [science] tags?
I've bumped into a question today tagged physics and I know there is already  food-science. Digging a bit deeper I found also science.
To me it's pretty clear we're discussing science from the point of view of cooking, so I believe we should merge / synonimize both science tags. Is there a good reason to keep them separated?

I doubt this has actually happened with the tags, but we do field questions that are only indirectly about food (e.g. cooking equipment), so in theory it's possible to have science questions that aren't food science. I didn't see anything tagged science that was obviously not-food, though, so I went ahead and merged. If anyone ever finds something lurking out there that badly needs equipment-science or whatever, they can tag it as such.
